# Set focus on fields in crm 2011 on onload event

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I m stucking in setting focus to a field in form after saving the record. Scenario: For user friendly wen user saves a form, after finishing the onload event execution, focus should be fixed to the last modified field. Tried many ways like isdirty, set focus on other field first and then exact field, but in all the times focus is focussing on the first field of the form. Pl help on this. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: to implement this kind of functionality you will need to write a big amount of unsupported javascript code, personally I think isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Tie all the fields to the same eventhandler. In this eventhandler, save the fields name
 to a variable in the global space (don't forget to pass the execution context as a parameter to this eventhandler to extract the fieldname)

In the form onload pick up this variable get the element and set focus to it.